# Why do the objects inside my json file initially load in a random order on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, slick.js

**Context in reduced test case scenario:** I have built a slider with 2 slides, each slide has a link named 'video' which when clicked upon shows another `<div>` which contains the array of objects (images).

**What the problem is:** When I click the 'video' link , the images should load in the same order as defined in the JSON array. They initially load in a random order, then when I drag the slider or click the 'Next'/'Previous' button to change the slide - the positions correct themselves. Why is this?

**Reduced test case** included

To reproduce my problem:

1. Go to the reduced test case
2. Click on the `<div>` inside the slider called 'VIDEOS'.

This will slide up another slider - which will have images. The image should start with the first index as it is in the JSON array, but shows the forth one instead.

3. Click the **Next** button inside the inner slider.

The slide will go to the image which contains the number '1', which is the correct order. Why do they load in a random order initially and how can I fix this?

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  draggable: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  fade: true
});

$('.content').appendTo($('.overlay'));

var imgListPrimary = "";
var imgListSecondary = "";

const jsonUrl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/19ony6";
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(json) {

  $.each(json.initial_slide.images, function() {
    imgListPrimary += '<div><img src= "' + this.src + '"></div>';
  });

  $.each(json.secondary_slide.images, function() {
    imgListSecondary += '<div><img src= "' + this.src + '"></div>';
  });

  $('.videos-slides').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    draggable: true,
  });

  $('.primary-card .videos-slides').slick('slickAdd', imgListPrimary);
  $('.second-card .videos-slides').slick('slickAdd', imgListSecondary);

});

$(".videos").click(function() {
  $(".videos-slider").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.videos-slider {
  display: none;
  background: #DDD;
}

.slick-dots {
  display: none !important;
}

.videos {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">

    <div class="slide primary-card">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="hero">
            <div class="video-poster">

              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=SLIDE1" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide second-card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="hero">
            <div class="video-poster">

              <img id="large" class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=SLIDE2" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="videos">
      <span class="title">VIDEOS</span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="slide" class="videos-slider">
    <div class="videos-slides">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: BTW, the variable `json` is not JSON, it's an object. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have fixed this post, please review and remove the negative mark?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Didn't mean to come across as rude so apologies my friend! Okay, no problem. I'll apply this to all future questions as I have been :)

Comment: No worries. :-) It's possible this is already pretty close to minimal anyway, given your problem appears to be with `slick`...

Answer (score 0):

Try **lazy loading** the images:

notice `lazyLoad: true` and `<img data-lazy=..."`

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  autoplay: false,
  draggable: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  fade: true
});

$('.content').appendTo($('.overlay'));

var imgListPrimary = "";
var imgListSecondary = "";

const jsonUrl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/ewjz2";
$.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(json) {

  $.each(json.initial_slide.images, function() {
    imgListPrimary += '<div><img data-lazy= "' + this.src + '"></div>';
  });

  $.each(json.secondary_slide.images, function() {
    imgListSecondary += '<div><img data-lazy= "' + this.src + '"></div>';
  });

  $('.videos-slides').slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    variableWidth: true,
    draggable: true,
  });

  $('.primary-card .videos-slides').slick('slickAdd', imgListPrimary);
  $('.second-card .videos-slides').slick('slickAdd', imgListSecondary);

});

$(".videos").click(function() {
  $(".videos-slider").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.videos-slider {
  display: none;
  background: #DDD;
}

.slick-dots {
  display: none !important;
}

.videos {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">

    <div class="slide primary-card">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="hero">
            <div class="video-poster">

              <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=SLIDE1" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide second-card">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="hero">
            <div class="video-poster">

              <img id="large" class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=SLIDE2" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="videos">
      <span class="title">VIDEOS</span>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="slide" class="videos-slider">
    <div class="videos-slides">

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This works but it causes a 'flash' to occur when you click next / previous buttons. This isn't ideal in my case